# PHP not showing error when I put only single = in if condition

Tags: php, if-statement

My code as follows:

```
if($_POST['user_id'] = ''){ 
  //some statement;
}
```

In the above `if` condition I have put only single `=`. PHP is not showing any error but I am getting a white blank page. Does anyone has any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if($_POST['user_id'] = '')` means:

`$_POST['user_id']` **becomes** '' .. `if ('')` // always false

`if($_POST['user_id'] == '')` means:

`$_POST['user_id']` **compares to**  '' .. `if ( comparison)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if trolling or real question...

you said it yourself, you're using a single `=`. You need 2 to check for equality.

```
if($_POST['user_id'] == ''){ 
  //some statement;
}
```

When you use a single equal sign, you're basically "set `$_POST['user_id']` to `''`, then test if it's `true`). Since `''` evaluates to `false`, you get nothing.

Comment: @BigJ - because it's not actually an error. It's perfectly valid to do that, it's just that just almost every time, it's not what you want to do.

Comment: @Madara Uchiha: guess who just now posted this comment? ;-)

Comment: @itachi: Not sure? (You're supposed to be dead)

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if($_POST['user_id'] = ''){
```

Tries to assign an empty string to `$_POST['user_id']`. This:

```
if($_POST['user_id'] == ''){
```

Is a comparison. You should almost always be doing the second one - the first one over-rides the value in $_POST, and returns the value of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

**try it**

Use it

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

if($user_id == ''){ 
  //some statement;
}
```

inseted of

```
if($user_id = ''){ 
  //some statement;
}
```

**Or try another one**

```
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];

if(isset($user_id) && !empty($user_id)){ 
  //some statement;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not triggering any error because it is a valid condition.

`if($_POST['user_id'] = '')`

equals to

```
$_POST['user_id'] = '';
if($_POST['user_id']){
    //Boolean comparison of a string. Empty = false. Not empty = true.
}
```

An example of use:

```
function division($var1, $var2){
    if($var2 > 0){
        return $var1/$var2;
    return false;
}

if($result = division(50,2)){
     //It returned 25 which is true!
}

if(!$result = division(50,0)){
    //Returned FALSE because you can't divide by zero!
}
```